# How to align bootstrap thumbnail

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap `thumbnail`. I want to **align them 3 thumbnails per row**. Please take a look at the picture. **This is what I want to happen:** [(Please Click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy7Da.png) *As you can see on the image, the* `thumbnail` are aligned 3 per row. But what I have right now is this: [(Please Click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDHxe.png) *On the image, they are aligned 1 per row*. Please note that I displayed the truck pictures and labels coming from the database. I just want to align them 3 `thumbnails` per row. Your help will be highly appreciated. Here is my **code**:

```
 <!-- IMAGE THUMBNAIL START -->
 <div class="row">

 <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
  <?php 
   include 'configmysqli.php';
   $query = "SELECT * FROM trucks ORDER BY TRUCK_TYPE ASC";
   $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>

   <div class="thumbnail">  
   <img src="<?=$row['TRUCK_PHOTO']?>" height="242" width="200" class="img-
      responsive img-rounded" alt="">
   <div class="caption">
   <form action="requesttruck.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-
     data">
    <h3><?=$row['TRUCK_TYPE']?></h3>
         <input type="text" name="companynum" hidden="true" value="<?
          =$row['COMPANY_NUM']?>">
         <input type="text" name="trucktype" hidden="true" value="<?
          =$row['TRUCK_TYPE']?>">

      <button class="btn btn-primary" name="request">Request</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" name="view">View</button>
  </form>
 </div> <!-- caption -->
</div> <!-- thumbnail -->

<?php
}
?>
</div> <!-- col -->
</div> <!-- row -->
<div class="col-sm-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need the loop outside `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">`

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` needs to enclose the column you are generating, otherwise you are just generating all your content in one single column.

Just a heads up, you're *probably* going to end up needing two loops eventually.  One to generate rows and one to generate columns (each thumbnail).

```
 <div class="row">

  <?php 
   include 'configmysqli.php';
   $query = "SELECT * FROM trucks ORDER BY TRUCK_TYPE ASC";
   $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
   <div class="thumbnail">  
   <img src="<?=$row['TRUCK_PHOTO']?>" height="242" width="200" class="img-
      responsive img-rounded" alt="">
   <div class="caption">
   <form action="requesttruck.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-
     data">
    <h3><?=$row['TRUCK_TYPE']?></h3>
         <input type="text" name="companynum" hidden="true" value="<?
          =$row['COMPANY_NUM']?>">
         <input type="text" name="trucktype" hidden="true" value="<?
          =$row['TRUCK_TYPE']?>">

      <button class="btn btn-primary" name="request">Request</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" name="view">View</button>
  </form>
 </div> <!-- caption -->
</div> <!-- thumbnail -->
</div> <!-- col -->
<?php
}
?>

</div> <!-- row -->
```